# Injecting Tailwind to a third party website and use library className

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tailwind-css

For some reasons, I need to inject Tailwind to youtube.com through a Chrome extension.

I use the content.js to load the script in :

```
const tailwindScript = document.createElement('script');
tailwindScript.src = 'https://cdn.tailwindcss.com';
document.head.appendChild(tailwindScript);
```

YouTube  element gave me that after inspecting DevConsole :

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

And Network pannel indicates that the library is well loaded :
[image]

However, after that, editing HTML element by adding this : `<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>` doesn't gave me the appropriate TailwindCSS styling for the h1 element.

Why classnames aren't effective here ?

Comment: trying to replicate locally, it is working for me - are the styles being injected? You can check the Elements pane to look at the styles for your h1 to see if they are there but are just overwritten.

Comment: The style aren't injected. I tried to reproduce step by step and again, creating a `<p class="text-red-500">TEST</p>` doesn't apply any style to the element. I checked again and the script is well loaded in the network tab.

Comment: you should not be looking at if the styles are _applied_ - they can be failing to be specific enough, and be being overridden. You want to check if they exist in the elements pane. If they do not, look for any errors in your console, it may be blocked by CSP or something similar when you go to add the stylesheet to the page